# Ubuntu 20.04.1, everything stops responding. Lenovo Thinkpad T14s AMD

Tags: 20.04, lenovo, thinkpad

Occasionally when using my new laptop all programs will stop responding or forcefully close. Also all icons, such as the symbol for Ubuntu Software, turn to a blank white box. At this point attempting to open anything causes nothing to happen at all and I cant even turn of the computer without holding down the power switch.

Answer (score 0):

In the BIOS setting of Lenovo:

> Config -> Power -> Sleep State

You might find the Sleep State of the BIOS as "Windows 10" by default. If it is the case, I believe that you should change it to "Linux" in case of your Ubuntu 20.04.1.

For me, after changing this "Sleep State" to "Linux", I observe no system hangs in  "Suspend" sleep mode anymore. Maybe this is also the case for you.

You can refer the location of the setting in the image below:

[image: BIOS Sleep State Image Captured]